# mod_rewrite bug and permission denied

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, seo

i'm using mod_rewrite to rewrite sites like "url.com/foo" to "url.com/index.php?site=foo".

The Code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?site=$1
```

If i click on a link with href="/foo" it will give me

```
http://url.com/foo/?site=foo
```

The code works at other sites on the same V-Server, i have Boilerplate installed, BUT i dont use the .htaccess of it right now to fix the mod_rewrite, so it cant be a boilerplate issue, or?

I also tried the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?site=$1
```

That code, at least,  rewrites to index.php?site=foo 
BUT it still creates url's like the upper example with the unnecessary folder between.

Edit: to make sure everyone understands the overall idea:

The files are based in http://url.com (index.php, .htaccess) , so i set the RewriteBase to "/".
It should take links like

```
http://url.com/foo
```

and rewrite them to

```
http://url.com/index.php?site=foo
```

there are no folders included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, damn i'm so stupid ;)

I have a folder called `url.com/foo/` and the link im redirecting is `url.com/foo` to `url.com/index.php?site=foo` so it is always trying to get into that folder. Since i renamed the folder it is working very well.

Answer (score 0):

I have been getting a similar error message on RewriteRule

```
pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

I also have the subfolder name similar to the redirected URL part but renaming it did not solve the problem (as suggested by Chris).

After multiple attempts, the problem was solved by updating the subfolder permissions to 755 (using cPanel folder permissions dialog) :

```
User:  Read, Write, Execute
Group: Read,        Execute
World: Read,        Execute
```

PS: I am not sure if renaming the subfolder was actually required for this scenario since before and after the rename, error message was same.